# Сортировка пузырьком, ошибка реализации

Tags: java

```
 // сортируем
          for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length-1 ; i++){
              boolean swapped = false;
              for(int j = arr.length-1 ; j > i ; j--){             
                  if( arr[j] > arr[j+1] ){
                      int tmp = arr[j];
                      arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                      arr[j+1] = tmp;   
                      swapped = true;
                  }               
              }
              if(!swapped)
                  break;
          }
```

Comment: а в чём вопрос?

Comment: что не  правильно?не работает

Comment: Решил его наконец))))

Answer (score 2):

Ну если кратко то нужно заменить строку

```
for(int j = arr.length-1 ; j > i ; j--)
```

на

```
for(int j = arr.length-2 ; j >= 0 ; j--)
```

Если этого не сделать то будет исключение `IndexOfBoundException` или что-то подобное, т.к. мы берём  элемент `j+1`, т.е. в начале цикла `j+1 =  arr.length` и такого элемента нет.

В реализации пузырька будет это условие `>= 0`, вы видимо перепутали с другой сортировкой. (Иначе просто неверно сортирует).

Так же вы могли воспользоваться отладчиком и пошагово посмотреть поведение программы.

Comment: отладчиком это как?

Comment: @ПетяПетросян если вы пишите код в любой среде разработки, то можно пошагово его исполнять, обычно это клавиши f7/f8/f4 и установка брейпоинта (точка остановки) по номеру строки (или где-то рядом). Более детально нужно смотреть в настройках конкретной среды.

Comment: Я правильно понял что в википедии, использован булев тип для решения вопроса с одиночным массивом, или зачем он нужен?

Comment: @ПетяПетросян не понял вопроса, киньте ссылку на статью или поясните что такое одиночный массив.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сортировка_пузырьком

Comment: состоящий из одного элемента, просто в википедии есть                      boolean swapped = false;  а на других учебных сайтах нет ..............

Comment: можно его не использовать, это оптимизация для случаев, когда массив сразу "почти отсортирован" (т.е. когда он сортируется за число проходов значительно меньше его длины).

Comment: Но он же (внешний цикл) гоняет внутренний цикл по всему массиву даже уже отсортированному!?

Comment: @ПетяПетросян вот для этого проверка и нужна. НО в целом, если нужна скорость то нужно использовать нормальный алгоритм за n log n. А если скорость не важна то и так можно.

Comment: задание у меня было, что бы массив уменьшался.......что бы отсортированные элементы не затрагивались, а вообще я буду использовать быструю сортировку..........здесь надо научиться вложенным циклам.........или подскажи , или буду думать сам дальше ....время терпит..........................

Comment: т.е. вы хотите скачать что быстрая сортировка _понятнее_ пузырька? или двойной цикл это сложно?

Comment: в джава быстрая сортировка реализована в библиотеке........

Answer (score 0):

```
// сортируем
for(int i = 0 ; i < arr.length-1 ; i++){
    boolean swapped = false;
    for(int j = arr.length-2 ; j >=i ; j--){               
        if( arr[j] > arr[j+1] ){
            int tmp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j+1];
            arr[j+1] = tmp; 
            swapped = true;
        }    
    }
    if(!swapped)
        break;
}
```